# Bit distance and disruption

Tags: algorithms, genetic-algorithms

Earlier, I asked [a question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27950/disruption-in-the-context-of-genetic-algorithms) defining disruption in Genetic Algorithms. Given that definition, I'm still confused on how to answer the following question.

> True or false? For  1-point  and  2-point  crossover,  the  schemata 
>   which  have  bits  that  are  close  together  on  the string encoding
>   are more likely to be disrupted by crossover.

From my understanding of cross-over disruption should only be dependant on the number of matching bits strings between parents. So `1001` would be more likely to be disrupted by `0110` then by `1000`. So I answered false, but their justification was that bits closer together encourage disruption, which I don't totally understand.

I'm assuming that "bit distance" can be defined as the number of zeros between sequential bits, but based on my proof above, I really don't see how this could affect disruption. Alternatively, I could consider "bit distance" as being the number of bits to flip to reach from one number to another, but based on my proof above, the greater the distance, the greater the chances of disruption.

Where is the mis-understanding between the official answer and my own?

Comment: If you don't like the answer that you gave in your previous question, then don't mark that answer as "correct."

Comment: I assumed that another question was justified since they are asking two different things, even if they are based off the same question. I marked my previous answer as correct, because I was able to figure out an acceptable (for my means) definition for "disruption", but as you noticed, I am unable to answer this one. That being said, I'm still new to this site, so let me know where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disruption refers to the phenomenon in which a schema represented by a particular parent is not passed down into its offspring.

That bit about schemata is important -- disruption isn't really defined except for in terms of schemata. Briefly, a schema is a **ternary** string containing 0s, 1s, and *s (don't-cares), whereas individuals are only binary (no *s). Each individual is a representative of $2^n$ schemata. For example,

```
10010011
```

is an instance of all of the following schemata:

```
1*******
*00**01*
1******1
...
```

The idea Holland had was that, for example, if good solutions tended to have a 1 in the leading bit, then the proportion of the population that is an instance of the schema

```
1*******
```

would increase over time according to a certain inequality. That's the schema theorem. Now, what if instead of that simple schema being more fit than average, we had a more complicated one, like

```
1*****0*
```

That is, suppose that individuals matching that pattern are above average in fitness. According to Holland, the GA should work by increasing the proportion of the population that conforms to that pattern over time.

But look at what happens with one-point crossover. It's going to pick a crossover point somewhere along the string and split it around that point. If both parents are instances of the schema, then both children will be as well. But if either parent is not an instance of the schema, then we have a probability that the children won't inherit that pattern. That failure to inherit the pattern is called disruption. Holland would have said that this was very bad. The presence of that schema in the population is evidence that it's good, and crossover is wrecking it. The modern understanding is much more nuanced than that, but that's the rationale behind considering disruption as a concept at least.

So you question asks whether schemata that have bits that are close together are more or less likely to be disrupted. We should really be more precise -- it's not whether any old bits are close together that matters. It's the distance between the first and last non-* bit that matters (called the defining length). The greater that distance, the more likely we'll put a crossover point in between them, and therefore the more likely we are to disrupt the schema.